# Show data in ionic template

Tags: templates, ionic-framework

so i want to show the result of geopositioning in my template view.I get the error "cannot read property coords of undefined" Below are the codes

```js
getGeolocationPosition() {

      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => { 
        
        var lati = resp.coords.latitude;
        var longi = resp.coords.longitude;
        // let pos = {
        //   lat: resp.coords.latitude,
        //   lng: resp.coords.longitude,
          
        // };
        console.log(lati, longi);
      }).catch((error) =>{
        console.log('Error getting location' + JSON.stringify(error) );
      });
    
  }
```

```html
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>What's your current location?</ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <button ion-button round (click)="getGeolocationPosition()">Get location</button>
      <ion-input readonly="true" placeholder="Latitude">{{resp.coords.latitude}}</ion-input>
      <ion-input readonly="true" placeholder="Longitude"></ion-input>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the class a property called geoResult and set it to the resp object from the async ionic native call.

this.geoResult = resp:

In your html, interpolate using geoResult

{{ geoResult.coords.latitude  }}